# TypeError astimezone() argument 1 must be datetime.tzinfo

Tags: python, cron, reddit

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to set up a Reddit bot and automate through crontab. When I run it through Python it works fine, but in crontab I'm getting the above: "TypeError astimezone() argument 1 must be datetime.tzinfo". I'm not sure how to fix this and haven't been able to find much about the issue online.

This is where I have the astimezone.

```
def timeStringToPacific(s):
    from_zone = tz.gettz('America/New_York')
    to_zone = tz.gettz('America/San_Francisco')
    time = datetime.strptime(s[:-3], '%I:%M %p')
    newyork = time.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    pacific = newyork.astimezone(to_zone)
    formatted = datetime.strftime(pacific, '%I:%M %p')
    if formatted[0] == '0':
        formatted = formatted[1:]
    return formatted
```

Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The string `"America/San_Francisco"` isn't a valid timezone, so, when you try to get it (with `tz.gettz("America/San_Francisco")`), it evaluates to `None`. This, in turn, causes the `TypeError`, as the method `astimezone` was expecting an argument of type `datetime.tzinfo` (but gets `NoneType` instead).

You can get a full list of timezones at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, than you so much!